# Entity Framework Code first fluent api relationships

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-fluent-api

I have a table `Items` and table `Services`.

Each item needs to have relation to one service.

How can I write relation between those 2 via `ItemServices` relational table in EF Fluent api?

Here are classes

```
public class Item
{
   public Guid Id { get; private set; }
   public Service Service { get;  private set; }
}

public class ItemService
{
    public int ServiceId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(ServiceId))]
    public Service Service { get; set; }

    public int ItemId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(ItemId))]
    public Item Item { get; set; }
}

public class Service
{       
    public int Id { get; private set; }

    public string ServiceCode { get; set; }
}
```

Please note that i do not want to have relation table inside my Item object, so I do not want to use it like `item.ItemService.Service`, but as a `item.Service`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On which version of Entity Framework you are working ?

If you ask about EF Core then you can find very good help here:

- [Entity Framework Core Relationships](https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/modeling/relationships.html)
- [Entity Framework Core Fluent API](https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/modeling/relationships.html#fluent-api)

BTW: I have similar case in my project and it's working by convention.

Of course I have configured `DbSet<>` in my `ApplicationDbContext`

*(I'm not sure how it's work in earlier versions of EF):*

**Is there something other reason for using ItemService object or it's for relationship purpose only ?**

If you use `ItemService` only for relationship purpose then you don't need it in your case - try something like that:

```
public class Item
{
   public Guid Id { get; set; }
   public Service Service { get; set; }
}

public class Service
{       
    public int Id { get; set; }    
    public string ServiceCode { get; set; }

    public Item Item { get; set; } //for One to One relationship
    // or
    public virtual ICollection<Item> Items { get; set; } // for One service to Many Items relationship
}
```

and in `ApplicaitionDbContext`:

```
public virtual DbSet<Item> Items { get; set; }
public virtual DbSet<Service> Services { get; set; }
```